# Одна или две Н в слове. Почему?

Tags: наречия, нн

Ведёт себя *упорядоченно*, спокойно.

На мой взгляд тут должно быть две Н, т. к. это наречие: Упорядочить — Упорядоченный — Упорядоченно. Верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, всё верно. Данное наречие образовано от отглагольного прилагательного "упорядоченный" (**не путать с причастием, имеющим ту же форму!**), в котором пишется -нн, поэтому пишется точно так же.

Comment: Спасибо. Оборот используют психиатры. А это не отглагольное прилагательное, не причастие?

Comment: @Алексей83 уже после отправки своего ответа увидел Вашу реплику про психиатров. Можете дать контекст?! Гугдом не находится. Есть единичное, весьма сомнительное причем, упоминание "упорядоченного поведения", но это явно не про то...

Comment: Это именно отглагольного прилагательное (если Вы о слове "упорядоченный"), т.к. **характеризует** предмет, а не описывает процесс совершения действия. Но, кстати, говоря, это слово может быть и причастием, обозначающим то, что предмет **был упорядочен**.

Comment: Бегемот, какая разница в принадлежности данного слова к сочетанию? Если сочетание относится к глаголу, то оно 100% является не образованным от причастия, а отглагольного прилагательного. Причём вопрос был даже не об этом, поэтому не надо здесь "самовозгораться".

Comment: @behemothus Вот [первая ссылка](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=509vjl0xnjoC&pg=PA167&dq=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F+%22%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif1PqEx6riAhWNmIsKHX9cBB8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%22%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&f=false) в гуглокнигах, достаточно солидная.

Comment: @grizzly - да, спасибо. Дело не в солидности, я хотел семантический ряд посмотреть. И не зря хотел, как оказалось. Сейчас ответ набросаю.

Comment: @БотБотович, вы же клон такого опытного форумчанина, а делаете вид, что не знаете, как надо обращаться. И не провоцируйте меня, пожалуйста, еще и тут на разборки, не одобряемые модераторами форума.

Answer (score 2):

Верно, если закрыть глаза на странноватое выражение "вести себя упорядоченно").

Comment: Я бы не стал закрывать глаза на то, что является ключевым в предложении и его оценки.

Comment: "Ключевой" здесь вопрос об Н/НН.

Comment: Не вижу ничего странного в этом выражении.

Comment: @grizzly в тексте моего ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Ведёт себя ***упорядоченно***, спокойно.

Существует прилагательное ***упорядоченный*** и образованное от него качественное наречие ***упорядоченно.***

**Почему в наречии пишутся две буквы НН**

От глагола ***упорядочивать*** образуется причастие ***упорядоченный***, которое может перейти в прилагательное, если утратит значение действия и приобретет качественное значение.

Но форма слова при этом не меняется, поэтому в отпричастном прилагательном пишутся две буквы НН, которые сохраняются и в наречии: **упорядоченн/ый — упорядоченн/о.**

**УПОРЯДОЧЕННЫЙ**, -1. Содержащийся в надлежащем порядке. У-ое собрание картин. У-ая коллекция. 2. Подчинённый определённому порядку, системе правил, построенный в соответствии с ними. **У-ая жизнь. У. режим дня.** У-ое изложение позиции. **<Упорядоченно, нареч.** **У. излагать мысли.**

Существуют выражения ***упорядоченный образ жизни, упорядоченный ум***,  из чего следует, что можно ***вести себя упорядоченно*** (организованно).

**Пример:** У каждого человека внутри есть своё представление об **упорядоченной жизни**.  Между тем во Вселенной всё **упорядочено**: действуют объективные законы.  Космос означает порядок.  Хаос означает беспорядок: беспорядочную жизнь, беспорядочное мышление, беспорядочную речь. https://podskazki.info/uporyadochennost/

Обратим внимание на краткое причастие с одной буквой Н: **всё упорядочено.**

Answer (score 0):

Неверно. Просто потому, что здесь очень сомнительно само употребление. Как это "вести себя упорядоченно"? Как наречие "упорядоченно" словарями вроде бы не фиксируется. Но если вы это слово и придумали, то вам и решать, наречие оно - или что.

UPD
Так, посмотрел я на контекст. Да, готов согласиться, что в таком употреблении это действительно наречие и требует удвоенного Н.
Сложность в том, что это, как выяснилось, термин профессиональной речи и напрямую выводить её из "упорядочить" нельзя, семантика здесь особая.
Я так понимаю, что ближайшим синонимом тут будет разговорное "адекватно", то есть без поведенческих флюктуаций. 
Почему это названо "упорядоченно" - надо спросить у специалистов, хотя и для них это видимо просто самодостаточный термин.

Слово "порядок" с производными вообще особое. Есть два явных значения (порядок как состояние: "здоровье в порядке", "порядок бьет класс" и "порядок" как контролирующая и регулирующая норма: "навести порядок") которые и сами по себе случается путаются. Но помимо того есть еще несколько "скрытых" значений, включая профессиональные термины ("порядок и мантисса" в математике, биологический порядок в систематике - и много еще чего).

Здесь мы, видимо, столкнулись еще с одним порядком, вернее "упорядоченностью", которую на самом деле никто не "упорядочивал". отсюда и мои первоначальные сомнения.

> Не вижу ничего странного в этом выражении

"Странность" здесь возникает при попытке объяснить семантику такой упорядоченности. Без расшифровки можно было бы предположить, что поведением кто-то командует, следит за порядком. Ну или на крайний случай, что речь идет о том, что поведенческая реакция подчиняется какому-то внутреннему порядку. Но, как вы, надеюсь, тоже понимаете речь совсем не о том, а об "адекватности" этого поведения, реакции на внешние раздражители - в противоположность галлюцинациям и бреду.

Comment: Немцы не довольствуются инстинктивным презрением к другим расам и народам, они хотят презирать на научном основании, презирать упорядоченно, организованно и дисциплинированно. [Н. А. Бердяев. Души народов (Параллели). Религия германизма (1914-1918)]

Comment: Вроде бы у Кузнецова и Лопатина фиксируется такое наречие.

Comment: @grizzly не в таком значении. В лучшем случае - в том, что shampar у Бердяева нашел, а тот у немцев). там в прямом смісле - упорядоченно, то есть с поддержанием некого порядка, на который немцы вообще мастера.